# d3 data not being retrieved from database

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working with a scatterplot in d3. Each dot represents a paper. On click of a dot I want to make a connection to the database and retrieve information on papers that are authored by the same author as the selected paper and display these papers on the graph. I have ran the connection to my query on my browser and manually inputted an author I know is in my database that have authored more than one paper. This retrieves the correct information. But when I try to use the same connection in d3, I can see in the console straight away that the authorName has not been grabbed and is undefined. Thus the following error is thrown later on `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined` Here is the relevant code for the connection:

```
clickHandler(d,i){

d3.json("connection11.php?authorName="+d.AUTHOR, function(error, dataJson) {

                console.log(dataJson); //undefined meaning it hasnt grabbed any data..?

                dataJson.forEach(function(d) {

                    d.YEAR = +d.YEAR;
                    d.counter = +d.counter;
                    d.type = "common author";

                allData.push(d);
                console.log(d.type);
                console.log(d);                 
                refreshGraph(); 

                })
            })
}
```

Can someone explain why this could be happening and what I should do differently fix this issue? I am new to d3 and any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
http://localhost/D3/connection11.php?authorName=%27Serge%20Abiteboul%27 which is the script containing the query returns:

`[{"ID":"69","AUTHOR":"Serge Abiteboul","In_order":"1","TITLE":"Foundations of Databases.\n","YEAR":"1995","Publication_Venue":"\n","In_library":"1","ID_from":"69","ID_to":"4","counter":"63"},{"ID":"2154","AUTHOR":"Serge Abiteboul","In_order":"1","TITLE":"Object Identity as a Query Language Primitive.\n","YEAR":"1992","Publication_Venue":"Building an Object-Oriented Database System, The Story of O2\n", "In_library":"0","ID_from":"2154","ID_to":"139","counter":"4"}]`

Which is parsable JSON as far as I can tell. This is the error found:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token Y
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Object.ia (http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js:3:3975)
    at XMLHttpRequest.u (http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js:1:10081) undefined`

Comment: Did you try to open and see if `"connection11.php?authorName="+d.AUTHOR` actually has valid json ? May be you should log `d` to see if it indeed has a valid `AUTHOR`.

Comment: @nikhil ohh ok I did log d and now very confused because that returns information but it isnt from the query in connection11.. I am now very confused ..

Comment: can you see a valid value in `d.AUTHOR` ?

Comment: @nikhil so `console.log(d);` shows info on that clicked paper. `console.log(dataJson);` should be showing info on the papers that have the same author as `d`. But it is currently just returning  `undefined`. so I am lead to believe the information from the query isnt being passed into dataJson..

Comment: what is the value of error parameter?

Comment: @TaranJ Not entirely sure what your asking sorry.. but it just says undefined when I look at dataJson in the console..

Comment: @JohnPower Try logging `console.log(error, dataJson)`. Parameter `error` might contain an error message.

Comment: @altocumulus ok yes there is very much an error there `SyntaxError: Unexpected token Y
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Object.ia (http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js:3:3975)
    at XMLHttpRequest.u (http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js:1:10081) undefined` this is a php error right? how do I fix this ..

Comment: @JohnPower No, it's a JS error. Have a look at this [question](/q/30677003). What does `"connection11.php?authorName="+d.AUTHOR` return? Are you sure it is parseable JSON?

Comment: @altocumulus it returns a string- the name of an author, I am pretty certain its parseable JSON... but the other connections I am using I use the ID of the paper to use in the query which hasnt caused any issues

Comment: @JohnPower Well, a string alone doesn't make up valid JSON. Could you please paste one example of the response into the question?

Comment: @altocumulus I put an edit to my question above I hope thats what you were looking for..? I am really grateful for your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106400/discussion-between-altocumulus-and-john-power).